# Stored procedure with optional parameter that doesn't show in SQL Server Management Studio "execute stored procedure" or "script stored procedure"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, sql-server-2014, ssms-2014

In SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), you can execute a stored procedure using the GUI for assistance.  This can done by right-clicking on the stored procedure in the Object Explorer and selecting either "Execute Stored Procedure" or "Script Stored Procedure as > CREATE to > New Query Editor Window".

Both of these result in a pre-built SQL query to execute the SP, and both of them include optional parameters from the SP.  Is there a way to make it so the optional parameters are "hidden"?

I have some user support folks who use SSMS to run certain SPs, and I don't want them providing values for certain optional parameters.  I want to be able to provide them myself, if needed, when I run the SP, but not the user support people.

I've tagged SQL Server 2014 and 2008 R2 in case there's some option I can set in the SP itself.

Comment: One way is to wrap procedure with another one and restrict access to some parameters. Then inside this procedure call your original one.

Comment: Thanks I had thought of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap your stored procedure with another:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.my_orig_proc
    @id INT
   ,@some_param_default INT = 10

AS
BEGIN
...
END
```

Wrapper:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.my_wrapper_proc
   @id INT
 AS
 BEGIN
     EXEC dbo.my_orig_proc @id;
 END
```

I would also restrict access to orignal procedures if necessary.

---

Another way is to add check and don't allow specific user to override value:

```
CREATE PROCEDRUE dbo.my_orig_proc
   @id INT,
   ,@some_param_default INT = 10
AS
BEGIN
   IF USER_NAME() = 'user_name' AND @some_param_default <> 10
      RAISERROR('You cannot change @some_param_default value' ,16,1);
END
```

Drawback: You need to change parameter value in two places and if user has impersonate privilige he still can execute it.